# Does someone create excel file with graph using apex?

Tags: apex, excel

I'm trying to create an excel file with graph's or anything that can display a Gantt chart so I can print it as PDF. my issue is that jquery and JS generated component cannot be rendered in a vfpage rendered as PDF. I want to rey not if we can create an excel file having a graph that resembles a Gantt chart

Comment: It is not _impossible_ to generate an XSLX file in Apex, but it _is_ difficult and complicated, and something Apex is thoroughly not suited to do. Consider building what you need on the front end using widely available JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Like David said in comment, you cannot create the same in the apex.

However, considering requirement - **anything that can display a Gantt chart so I can print it as PDF**, it is possible using google charts.

Idea is first you create a chart and it'll give you the image URL. And use that image url in your PDF.

Imagine on load you created chart on VF page (One.vfp) and from that you have a button "Print PDF", which will invoke Two.vfp and where you can pass the image address in the URL of Two.vfp, so that it'll render image.

**Reference -**

**Gantt chart** - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart

**Print PNG from chart**  - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing